# Hover over Cart in WordPress

Tags: css

I own a website that I've build in lately. Everything works fine but I came across an issue.
Whenever one of my clients adds a product to cart. The hover effect is looking super strange, like is the CSS would broke or smthin. I am using Astra Pro Theme, tried turning off plugins, updating plugin / theme, checking if maybe function.php has any issue but nope. Can anyone solve this for me?

boxbouquet.ca/product/you-had-me-at-moet You can add any item, and it will appear exactly same, this is just a one of the products links - click "Add to cart" and hoover over it.

[image]

Comment: Can you give me your site url to can check the bug for you?

Comment: https://boxbouquet.ca/product/you-had-me-at-moet/

You can add any item, and it will appear exactly same, this is just a one of the products links - click "Add to cart" and hoover over it.

Comment: I see but it looks working for me .. i can see  View cart / Checkout in both firefox and chrome.. which browser you use?

Comment: It works - but it looks super strange? Like on the picture attached? Not displaying correctly. 
https://wpastra.com/docs/shortcode-for-astra-mini-cart/

Like here the cart is pretty - and thats how it looked before.
Now it has no margins, and the layout of preview doesnt look to well.

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please take the time to read **https://stackoverflow.com/tour** and **https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask**. `The Wordpress tag is for programming-specific questions about the WordPress content management system ONLY.` Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc. These are best asked on the dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site (**https://wordpress.stackexchange.com**).

Comment: Ah, I understand, its just css.. you modified some css file or css properties on the theme?

Comment: I've added long time ago CSS in "Customize-Additional CSS" section, but I've even tried taking out all CSS and it's still broken